# Laravel 5 php artisan migrate --database parameter not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, console, migration

i want to migrate database using console command

when i try `php artisan migrate` is working, but when i try `php artisan migrate --database="test"` is not working it said

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]       
 Database [test] not configured.
```

what's wrong ? this is `php artisan migrate --help`

```
 Usage:
 migrate [options]

Options:
--database[=DATABASE]  The database connection to use.
--force                Force the operation to run when in production.
--path[=PATH]          The path of migrations files to be executed.
--pretend              Dump the SQL queries that would be run.
--seed                 Indicates if the seed task should be re-run.
-h, --help                 Display this help message
-q, --quiet                Do not output any message
-V, --version              Display this application version
--ansi                 Force ANSI output
--no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
-n, --no-interaction       Do not ask any interactive question
--env[=ENV]            The environment the command should run under.
```

**UPDATE**

after i realise it's not database name, but database connection.. but i need to call database name, because i call this from another project to create new database and migrate it. so i need to be dynamic.. how to achieve that ?

Comment: So is your `test` database configured?

Comment: yes, test is my database name, and it's working if i not using parameter --database, i set `DB_DATABASE=test` in my environment i just run `php artisan migrate` it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some package that working perfectly what i need..

https://packagist.org/packages/a2way/laravel-tenant-migrate

i can run `migrate:tenant (connection-name) (database-name)` for create database for every tenant..

Comment: Thank you for sharing the word about the package I created. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked config/database.php and look at the 'connections' array? Try something like this (In the example I'm using mysql):

```
'connections' => [

        // Replace mysql with your DB driver
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'test' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],


    ],
```

In your .env file, you shouldn't have any DB_ parameters set. If you run php artisan migrate with the above setup, it will migrate to the homestead database. If you run php artisan migrate --database=test, it will migrate to the test database.

Comment: as i describe above, i realise that is a database connection so i need create a new connection.. but the problem now is this is SaaS and each tenant will have their own database setup. so it's imposible to use this solution if i have  a lot of tenant

Comment: It might be worth having a quick look on Google since there are already multiple questions about SaaS and Laravel - I've found this which seems to be more along the lines of what you're looking for! https://github.com/leemason/tenantable

Comment: ok after more research i found this https://packagist.org/packages/a2way/laravel-tenant-migrate thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
env('DB_DATABASE', 'test')
```

This is the cause.

The settings in the .env file are read.

I set ⇃.

```
'database' => 'test',
```